# Asus g501 Multitouch not working on 16.04

Tags: drivers, asus, multi-touch, elantech

I just did a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 but the multitouch doesn't work which makes it very hard to work. Here are the issues I'm facing;

- Since the left and right click buttons are part of the touchpad, they aren't detected and this causes the mouse to move when trying to right or left click
- Palm interferes with typing
- No two finger scrolling

My `xinput list` output is;

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ FTE1001:00 0B05:0101                      id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam                      id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

If it helps, my kernel version is 4.4.0-22-generic and BIOS is G501VW.206.

Comment: Same thing happened to me on a ThinkPad T540p.

Comment: did you fix it or is it still an issue?

Comment: Still an issue.

Comment: Actually, it's only two-finger scrolling that doesn't work in my case -- The left/right/middle mouse buttons built into the top edge of the touchpad do work.

Comment: I've filed a bug so hopefully I can get a resolution from there